# Why can't I connect to my Postgres db via Heroku CLI?

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-cli

I have used this functionality many times in the past, and Heroku docs still say this command is the correct way to connect to your Postgres db via CLI, so any ideas why this might be happening?:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that runs into this issue, I updated my CLI (I was behind a couple minor versions), logged out of heroku and back in via CL, now it works ¯_(ツ)_/¯